# Can an integer in vhdl have an X or Z value?

Tags: vhdl

I was curious if I need to initialize an integer in vhdl to get a value of zero by default.

Would an integer initialize as a zero or an X?

Answer (score 4):

No. An integer is purely a numerical type - is has no binary representation, hence cannot have meta values.

The default integer type range is implementation defined, but most current implementations use a nearly full 32 bit range, from -2^31+1 to 2^31-1.

All types initialise by default to `type'left`

Comment: The standard says the an implementation shall at least provide that range, hence, integer'left may be -2^31

Comment: Note that `integer'left` is the same as `integer'low`, which is the smallest of all integers (e.g. `-2^31+1` or `-2^31` depending on your implementation).

Comment: however a NATURAL would initialise to NATURAL'left = 0. You have a type system ... use it to make life easier.